# Reset Device Chooser to allow device choice

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

How do you reset the Device Chooser so that it WILL show up again?

By this I mean that I have an AVD running and selected the **Use same device for future launches** but when I was ready / needed to try the app on a real device, I of course lose that option.

Current workaround is restart Eclipse but leave the AVD running.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on Project -> Properties -> Run/Debug Settings -> Delete the profile that is there. You can always edit the profile to "Always prompt to pick  device" (Target tab if you click edit) but deleting it is easier.

Comment: @AVEbrahimi It runs fine on the Linux 64-bit Android ADT bundle provided by Google which uses Eclipse 4.2.0 (at time of writing). Have you tried just outright deleting the profile instead of just editing the config?